# How to handle br and gz files in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm using brotli-webpack-plugin and compression-webpack-plugin to compress my js/html/css files.

after I run webpack, it creates `.br` and `.js.gz` files per js file.

My question is how I serve in nodejs those files? currenctly I serve using static middleware.

Should I serve `.br`/`.gz` files instead of the js?

```
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");
const BrotliPlugin = require("brotli-webpack-plugin");

new BrotliPlugin({
    asset: "[path].br[query]",
    test: /\.(js|css|html|svg)$/,
    threshold: 10240,
    minRatio: 0.7
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a fallback mechanism since not all browsers supports all types.

One way would be:

Read [`Accept-Content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding) header, check it what type the browser supports and serve the best file type for the request.

Fortunately, there is a lib for that, [express-static-gzip](https://github.com/tkoenig89/express-static-gzip#readme).

```js
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const expressStaticGzip = require('express-static-gzip');
const app = express();

// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname))); replace this with the line below

app.use(
  '/',
  expressStaticGzip(path.join(__dirname), {
    enableBrotli: true,
    orderPreference: ['br'],
  }),
);
```